# How to enable customer community users via apex

Tags: apex, user-record, customer-community

We have person accounts in our org. to whom we need to give access to our customer community at various stages of an opportunity.

Is there a way we can programmatically  enable our person accounts as customer users using apex ?

We have ***Customer Community Login*** licenses available in our org.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create Customer Community User programmatically using apex by assigning Customer Community Profile and set ContactId of the user to account.PersonContactId;

```
 newUser.ContactId = account.PersonContactId ;
```