# UserId shows null .How to solve this problem?

Tags: code-coverage

I have created a resgistration page for community user so that whenever he registers his details in the page a user gets created in the org.

Now, I have to write a test class for it . It is showing that userId is null although I am entering all the user credentals in it

I am writing the code  and the corresponding test class below .Please guide me how to achieve more test coverage.Thanks in advance

```
public class CommunitiesSelfRegisterController {

public String firstName {get; set;}
public String lastName {get; set;}
public String email {get; set;}
public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
public List<User>userList{get;set;}

public CommunitiesSelfRegisterController () {
    userList=new List<User> ();
    String FirstName = '';
    String LastName='';       
}

public PageReference registerUser() {

    String profileId = Label.CommunityUser; // To be filled in by customer.
    String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
    String accountId = Label.AccountId; // To be filled in by customer.

    String userName = email;
    system.debug('FirstName:::'+firstName);
    system.debug('LastName:::'+lastName);

    User u = new User();
    u.Username = userName;
    u.Email = email;
    u.FirstName = firstName;//FirstName
    u.LastName = lastName;
    u.CommunityNickname = email;
    u.ProfileId = profileId;

    String userId;
    system.debug('user::::'+u);
    try {
        userId = Site.createExternalUser(u, accountId, password);
        system.debug('accountId:::'+accountId); 
        system.debug('password:::'+password);
        system.debug('u:::'+u);
        system.debug('userId:::'+userId);
    } catch(Site.ExternalUserCreateException ex) {

    }

    if (userId != null) { 
        if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
            return Site.login(userName, password, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startURL'));
        }
        else {
            PageReference newpage = new PageReference('/QueryBuilderPage');
            newpage.setRedirect(true);
            return newpage;
        }
    }
    return null;
}      
}
```

Test class:

```
   @IsTest
   public class CommunitiesSelfRegisterController_Test {
   @isTest(SeeAllData=false)
   public static void testCommunitiesSelfRegisterControlle(){
    Profile profile = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Customer Community Login User']; 

    schema.Account account = new schema.Account(Name='Test Account Name');
    insert account;

    Contact contact=new Contact();
    contact.LastName='Test';
    contact.AccountId=account.Id;
    insert contact;

    User user=new User();
    user.Email='test@force.com';
    user.Username='test@force.com';
    user.FirstName='Class';
    user.LastName='Test';
    user.Alias='testf';
    user.CommunityNickname='test@force.com';
    user.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
    user.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
    user.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
    user.ProfileId=profile.Id;
    user.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
    user.ContactId=contact.id;
    user.IsActive = true;
    insert user;        

    CommunitiesSelfRegisterController communitiesSelfRegisterController= new CommunitiesSelfRegisterController();
    System.runAs(user){
        communitiesSelfRegisterController.firstName=user.FirstName;
        communitiesSelfRegisterController.lastName= user.LastName;
        communitiesSelfRegisterController.email=user.Email;
        communitiesSelfRegisterController.password='remainder';       
        communitiesSelfRegisterController.confirmPassword='remainder';                      
    }
    communitiesSelfRegisterController.registerUser();       
}
}
```

Comment: Are there any exception in your try catch block? coz you used the same username for in your test class.

Comment: Assign a role to the user, who is the owner of the account. Refer more at this thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102170/test-class-issue-with-unknown-exception-portal-account-owner-must-have-a-role

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are inserting a user in your test method and your controller is trying to create another user with the same username.

I think you should not try to insert the user in your test method. Just provide the details and let your Controller create the user.

Do an assert in the test method to check if the community user has been successfully created.

Comment: Hii Aslam,  I tried not to insert the user in the test method .But it is still showing the same result Userid is null

Comment: Maybe for some reason the user is not getting created then. Is the password valid? Could it be that the password you are supplying in the test method is not complex enough? Try giving an alpha numeric with special characters.

Comment: I tried with an alphanumeric password also but still it is showing the same result